# How can I get thumbnail images to take up the whole space of the thumbnail?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

How can I make the images in the thumbnails take up the whole space of the thumbnail so that the overlay div ("November") and the slideToggle div ("Women & Girls in STEM") don't stick out?

I use jQuery and Bootstrap. When the user hovers over the image, the slideToggle slides up, then disappears when the mouse leaves. But it doesn't fit the image; nor does the November overlay.

[image]

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.thumbnail').hover(function () {
        $('.slider', this).slideToggle('fast');
    });
    //$('.thumbnail').hover(function () {
    //    $('.slider', this).animate({
    //        opacity: 0.75,
            
    //        height: "toggle"
    //    }, 750, function () {
    //        //Animation complete.
    //    });
    //});

});
```

```css
.womens-overlay {
    position: absolute;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,1);
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    padding: 2%;
    width: 35%;
    color: #FFFFFF;
}

/*Removes the automatic thumbnail frames.*/
.thumbnail {
    border: none;
    box-shadow: none;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    margin: 5px;
    color: #333;
}

.thumbnail img {
    max-height: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
}

.thumbnail .slider {
    border: none;
    box-shadow: none;
    display: none;
    opacity: 0.8;
    background: #D2D6E2;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    bottom:4px;
    padding: 5px;
}

.slider {
    position: absolute;
    padding-top: 0%;
}
```

```html
            <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">
                <div class="image-box">
                    <div class="thumbnail">
                        <img src="Images/celebrating-women-in-stem.jpeg" />
                        <div class="womens-overlay">
                            <h3>November</h3>
                        </div>
                        <div class="slider">
                            <h2>Women & Girls in STEM Month</h2>
                            <h3>EVENT</h3>
                            <p>This November, we are celebrating women and girls in STEM. Come join us!</p>
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Learn More</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add an each function so it will work on multiple thumbnails. Then get the height of the thumbnail and set the .slider height to the same.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
     $('.thumbnail').each(function(){
           // get height
           var height = $(this).height();
           // set slider height
           $(this).children('.slider').css({'height':height+'px'});
           $(this).hover(function () {
                $(this).children('.slider').slideToggle('fast');
           });
      });
});
```

Then set overflow:hidden on the .thumbnail

```
.thumbnail {
    border: none;
    box-shadow: none;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    margin: 5px;
    color: #333;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

fiddle - https://fiddle.jshell.net/Jim_Miraidev/xrevsesq/

Comment: No problem, glad to help :)